# Date format Convertion issue in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i could not convert string date into NSDate object.
Please check below code

```
let stringDate = "06:30 AM" 
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat="hh:mm a"
let local = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
formatter.locale=local
let date = formatter.dateFromString(stringDate)
```

Comment: what the error u faced..?

Comment: it converts fault result

Comment: can u show the result ..

Comment: I tried, it is converting "Jan 1, 2000, 6:30 AM"

Comment: @RobIN It seems fine as per code, what is expected result?

Comment: i got result like this
2000-01-01 01:00:00 +0000

Comment: Are you in India (+5:30)?

Comment: yes... 
did i missed anything

Comment: with out this `let local = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
formatter.locale=local` try once

Answer (score 1):

The output is as expected, and depending on what you're trying to achieve, you haven't really done anything wrong.

Your `stringDate` instance contains only information about a *time of the day*, not a *date* (the prior is also the only format your `NSDateFormatter` `formatter` is "interested" in). Hence, the following snippet produces the expected `06:30 AM` output:

```
let stringDate = "06:30 AM"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat="hh:mm a"
let local = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
formatter.locale=local

if let date = formatter.dateFromString(stringDate) {
    print(formatter.stringFromDate(date)) // 06:30 AM
}
```

`NSDate` instances are defined, however, as single point in *time* (date and hour of the day), with reference to an absolute reference date:

> `NSDate` objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of
>   any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date objects are
>   immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an
>   absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001).

From the [language reference for `NSDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/).

Hence, in addition to a *time of day*, `NSDate` instances include also a *date* (even if this is not, in your case, used or displayed). When you assign a value to `date` above, the Swift playground displays the *time of day* of the correct *date*; the latter offset by `06:30` from the absolute reference date, `2000-01-01 00:00:00`. If we modify the example above to print all details in the final print statement, we see this more clearly:

```
// ...

if let date = formatter.dateFromString(stringDate) {
    formatter.dateStyle = .FullStyle
    formatter.timeStyle = .FullStyle
    print(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
    /* Saturday, January 1, 2000 at 6:30:00 AM Central European Standard Time */
}
```

---

*(Addition with regard to your comments below)*

Note the difference of printing the *date object itself* (e.g. `print(date)` above) and *printing a ** formatted string representation** of the date using your formatter* (e.g. `print(formatter.stringFromDate(date))`). The prior just prints the `.description` property of your date, which is an default-formatted string representation of the contents of object itself rather than a controlled formatted output of the date:

> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> var description: String { get }
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> A string representation of the date object. (read-only)
>
> *The representation is useful for debugging only.*
>
> There are a number of options to acquire a formatted string for a date
>   including: date formatters (see `NSDateFormatter` and *Data Formatting
>   Guide*), and the `NSDate` methods `descriptionWithLocale:`,
>   `dateWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:`, and
>   `descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:`

Refer to my code blocks above to see how you can *print*  the formatted date using your `NSFormatter`.

Comment: absolutely right
i have print the date object in the log , but its looks like : 2000-01-01 01:00:00 +0000

Comment: i need a NSDate object with 06:30 AM details

Comment: @RobIN that date is as per the expectation in UTC when you will print it via dataformatter you will get IST there

Comment: @RobIN Note the different of printing the _date object itself_ (e.g. `print(date)` above) and _printing the **string representation** of the date using your formatter_ (e.g. `print(formatter.stringFromDate(date))`). The prior just prints the `.description` of your date, which is an unformatted description of the contents of object itself rather than a controlled formatted output of the date. Refer to my first code block above; printing the date in the format specified by your `NSFormatter`.

Comment: @RobIN Have you tried using your `formatter` instance (method `.stringFromDate(...)`) to get a formatted string representation of the date? (That you can subsequently print to your console)